# Update action doesn't update data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with update action - for PUT method from REST. 
When I try update a row (task in my case) it stays the same. Nothing changes.

My application is a simple 'TO DO' list. User can create a task, edit and and browse tasks.

I have controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @task = Task.new
    @tasks = Task.all
  end


  def create
    Task.create(task_params)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.save
    redirect_to tasks_path
  end

  private
  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:task)
  end

end
```

And model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And the partial:

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :task, "Type your task:", id: "task" %>
  <%= f.text_field :task %>
  <%= f.submit "Create!", id: "add_task" %>
<% end %>
```

For this view:

```
<h1>Edit</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the `@task` with the params

```
def update
   @task = Task.find(params[:id])
   if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
     redirect_to tasks_path   
   else
     render action: :edit
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the new values of the Task. With `find` you just fetch the record, you don't perform any actual update on the existing object.